# Combinatorics - group arrangement

Tags: combinatorics

You have $7$ women and $5$ men and we choose a group of $5$ people out of the total.
In how many ways can you choose so that the absolute value between the number of men and women is no greater than $1$ (either $3$ men and $2$ women or $2$ men and $3$ women)?

I think it is $(5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3)(7 \cdot 6)+(7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5)(5 \cdot 4)$.

Comment: Fairly big overcount. You are to some extent counting order of selection as significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a permutation.

Observe that a two-person committee consisting of Abigail and Barbara is the same as one consisting of Barbara and Abigail.  Hence, the order in which the women are selected does not matter, nor does the order in which the men are selected.

The number of ways of selecting three of the five men is $\binom{5}{3}$.  For each such selection, there are $\binom{7}{2}$ ways of selecting the two women.  The other possibility is that two of the five men are selected and three of the seven women are selected, giving a total of

$$\binom{5}{3}\binom{7}{2} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{7}{3}$$

committees in which the number of men and women on the committee differs by at most one.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Combinatorics_and_statistics). Quoting.

> There are ${n \choose k}$ ways to choose $k$ elements from a set of $n$ elements. See [Combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Firstly note, that exist ${7 \choose 2}$ choices to take two women from group of seven. Each group you can assign ${5 \choose 3}$ groups of man. So, you have ${7 \choose 2} \cdot {5 \choose 3}$ possibilities of groups with $2$ women and $3$ man.

Similarly, you have ${7 \choose 3} \cdot {5 \choose 2}$ groups of 3 women and 2 man. So, the [answer is 560](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=choose%287%2C2%29*choose%285%2C3%29%20%2B%20choose%287%2C3%29*choose%285%2C2%29).

$$\begin{split}
{7 \choose 2} \cdot {5 \choose 3} + {7 \choose 3} \cdot {5 \choose 2} &=
\frac{7!}{2! \cdot 5!} \cdot \frac{5!}{3! \cdot 2!} + \frac{7!}{3! \cdot 4!} \cdot \frac{5!}{2! \cdot 3!}\\
&=\frac{6 \cdot 7}{2} \cdot 10 + \frac{5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7}{6} \cdot 10\\
&=210 + 350 = 560
\end{split}$$

---

Why $(7\cdot 6 \cdot 5)(5 \cdot 4) + (7 \cdot 6)(5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3)$ is wrong? Because, here order doesn't matter. Look, you want take two girls from set of three. Your possibility:

$$ 1~2\\ 1~3\\ 2~3$$

So it's just ${3 \choose 2} = \frac{3!}{2! 1!} = \frac{6}{2}=3$ choices. Not $3\cdot 2 \cdot 1=6$.

$$1~2\\1~3\\2~1\\2~3\\3~1\\3~2$$

Because $3~2$ is same to $2~3$.